# Android studio: Auto completion not working with ctrl + space

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Android studio: Auto-completion not working with **ctrl + space** and working but lagging(suggestions are loading slowly with a loading icon) with **ctrl + shift + space**.

Tried all the following based on the previous similar question:

1. made sure power save mode is off.
2. invalidated and restarted.
3. made sure relevant checkboxes are checked in code completion settings.

Also, suggestions are working with flutter project in Android studio but not with android project. Tried for solutions but didn't find any relevant doc.

Moreover, it used to show suggestions just after pressing '.' even without shortcuts. Updated some versions and the feature is disturbed. Does code completion depend on anything else?

Edit: suggestions are appearing but it's taking about **5 secs** after pressing '.' or ctrl + space

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was showing only for exact text case but after below steps it was working as expected.
`File->Settings-> Editor -> General -> Code Completion`.
Uncheck Match case checkbox if its checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

1.Close Android studio then go to the folder where android studio is located 
 Or you can go to the

drive C -> users -> find .gradle file and do below things

2. Find .gradle file -> In .gradle folder delete caches folder 
   then restart android studio sync your files with gradle ....
   its work for me :D